# Using tensorboard in pytorch, but get blank page?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard, torch, tensorboardx

I am using tensorboard in pytorch 1.3.1, and I did exactly the same in the [pytorch docs for tensorboard](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html).
After running `tensorboard --logdir=runs`, I got this:

[image].

```
$ tensorboard --logdir=runs
TensorFlow installation not found - running with reduced feature set.
Serving TensorBoard on localhost; to expose to the network, use a proxy or pass --bind_all
TensorBoard 2.1.0 at http://localhost:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

And after opening http://localhost:6006/, I got blank page like this [image]

I also tried tensorboardX, and got the same result. Could you please tell how to solve the problem? thx.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this problem in tensorboard version >= 2.0.
What I did is add `--bind_all`
You can try:

```
tensorboard --logdir=runs --bind_all
```

Comment: Got this: `tensorboard: error: unrecognized arguments: --bind_all`

Answer (score 2):

I am using Torch 1.4.0 on Windows and I had the same issue. Turns out I had installed the 2.x version of Tensorboard. I reverted back to 1.15.0 and it solved the issue.

Comment: 2.0.2 seems to be the most recent working version with this setup.

Comment: Apart from that I had to `pip uninstall torch-tb-profiler`,  only the 1.15.0 downgrade worked for me and my `torch==1.9.0+cu111`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running 
`tensorboard --logdir=runs` from the same dir as 'runs'

Answer (score 0):

You may want to update both toolboxes to the latest version. The following resolved my problem:

```bash
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow tensorboard
```

Of course as Andrei mentioned, make sure the path to the results are correct:

```bash
tensorboard --logdir=PATH_TO_RESULTS
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to run in terminal

```
`venv\Scripts\activate`
in your project directory 
then 
`tensorboard --logdir results --port 6006`
and you got it
```