# Tensorboard in pytorch does not load anything in Browser

Tags: pytorch, tensorboardx

I am using tensorboard to monitor the training progress of the model from this [codebase](https://github.com/ClementPinard/SfmLearner-Pytorch). To open tensorboard, I ran the command `tensorboard --logdir=checkpoints/` as suggested in the codebase. I know that to open tensorboard, I need to pass the directory path in `--logdir` where the events file is present, which I did. It does seem to open tensorboard since it returns the following in the terminal.

```
I0620 12:52:16.737502 140647693104896 plugin.py:292] Monitor runs begin
TensorBoard 2.5.0 at http://localhost:8088/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But when I open the link in browser, this [tensorboard loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOgRO.png) occurs and it loads forever, and doesnt open any stats/plots that I want to visualize.

My tensorboard version is 2.5.0 and pytorch version is 1.8.1+cu102

Comment: Are you sure there is any events file in the `checkpoints/` dir?

Comment: I use Vscode and have the same problem but Google Colab is ok. I saw a post yesterday that had the same issues.

Comment: Though the author of the repository suggested `checkpoints/` dir ,  the events file were inside several subfolders in  `checkpoints/Data/time-of-epochcompletion/`. So, I also tried passing these subfolder paths where the events file were present, and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

This issue got resolved once I uninstalled torch_tb_profiler and downgraded Tensorboard 2.5.0 to 1.15.0 as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308202/using-tensorboard-in-pytorch-but-get-blank-page)